# Verify that you have access to that Directory

Tags: permissions, wix

I have a Wix installer which copies files into the SQL server Directory.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Connections

Error:

[image]

If I run my installer from a command prompt with admin permissions it works. However this is not something I think I can require of users.

How can I force the installer to run only using admin permissions?

I have tried

```
<Property Id="MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION" Value="1" />
```

and

```
 InstallPrivileges="elevated"
```

neither seam to force the installer to only run with admin access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I had install scope set to perUser.

```
 <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perUser" InstallPrivileges="elevated" />
```

After consulting the documentation.  [Package Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html) I found under InstallScope

> Set this value to declare that the package is a per-machine
>   installation and requires elevated privileges to install.

I changed the install scope to `perMachine` and it now forces you to install it with admin permissions.

```
 <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" InstallPrivileges="elevated" />
```